# Is it possible to create a global workflow for GitHub actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am managing several projects using GitHub actions.

Every repository consist of several workflows which happens on push to branches and on pull requests. Keeping all this configuration (even when sharing actions) is hard.

Is it possible to create and use one global workflow for an event?

Comment: You can turn the workflows into a docker image and finally an action that uses that docker image to instrument the workflow. You can follow an example given [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action)

Comment: i would like to keep the steps in the workflow... not just one giant step for the docker image...